# Distributing a Spotify application without it being available on the public Spotify platform

Tags: spotify

Can I build and distribute a spotify app without it being on the Spotify application platform?  In other words, can I drive traffic to Spotify and allow them to use the application through Spotify without it being on the public platform?

Answer (score 1):

The only way at the moment is to manually distribute your application and have everyone who wants to use it sign up for a Spotify developer account so they can access your application manually.

It may be wise to contact the Apps team (there's a contact form on the developer website) and see if they can help you.